# What is the mathematical meaning of the returned variable?

Tags: python, mcmc

What exactly are the numbers `g1` and `g2` in this Python code, in terms of their mathematical significance?

This is part of an MCMC simulation that I'm trying to adapt for Julia, but I can't figure this part out.

```
def q(x, y):
    g1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(x, y, 1.0, 1.0, -1, -1, -0.8)
    g2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(x, y, 1.5, 0.8, 1, 2, 0.6)
    return 0.6*g1+28.4*g2/(0.6+28.4)
```

Comment: Its a weighed average. I think the numbers are arbitrary

Comment: If you want to know about `bivariate_normal`... http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariateNormalDistribution.html

Comment: @cricket_007 _wrongly implemented_ weighted average to be precise.

Comment: @cricket_007 so the function returns a weighted average (which for some reason has weight 29, OK). What exactly are g1 and g2? Are those some parameters of the distribution, or values of the distribution at (x,y)?

Comment: They are the bivariate normal. I'm not a mathematician, so can't say *exactly*

Comment: Bummer. The bivariate normal is a distribution, but g1 is a number. It's not the math that I have a problem with but I'm not very experienced with Python and this has me pretty confused. Thanks for your help either way!
Edit: typo.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question and it's unclear to me if 0.6*g1+28.4*g2/(0.6+28.4) should really be (0.6*g1+28.4*g2)/(0.6+28.4) but g1 and g2 are, I think, probability densities. I don't know what the weighted sum in the return statement is supposed to be